# What is a better, more idiomatic way of writing this Ruby method?

Tags: ruby, caching, refactoring

This is a simple method to check a cache and make an expensive API call for a cache miss.

```
    def search_for params
      cache = Cache.for( params )
      return cache if cache

      response = HTTParty.get( URL, params )
      Cache.set params, response

      response
    end
```

But it seems wordy and not idiomatic.

Answer (score 4):

Does Cache.set return the Cache object that is set? If so, this may work:

```
def search_for params
  Cache.for(params) || Cache.set(params, HTTParty.get( URL, params ))
end
```

Comment: Although this is clean, I'm not sure why the `Cache#set` should return the value. It seems strange to depend on that...

Answer (score 2):

Let's do something crazy.

### Add `[]` and `[]=` to `Cache`

```
Cache.instance_eval do
  alias_method :[], :for
  alias_method :[]=, :set
end
```

### Create a module to reuse

```
module Cacheable
  def cached(key)
    Cache[key] ||= yield
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend self
  end
end
```

### Use the `Cacheable` module

```
class Foo
  include Cacheable

  # `cached` can be used in instance methods
  def search_for(params)
    cached(params) do
      HTTParty.get(URL, params)
    end
  end

  # `cached` can also be used in class methods
  def self.search_for(params)
    cached(params) do
      HTTParty.get(URL, params)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In a way, it seems like it might be better to use a module instead of a class for Cache. I can see how different classes that make API requests would be Cacheable.

Answer (score 1):

Another option based on your question

```
def search_for params
  unless response = Cache.for( params )
    response = HTTParty.get( URL, params )
    Cache.set params, response
  end
  response
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify implementation of `Cache#for` and have it accept a block that will be executed if value is not found in cache, then, it can simplify the calling sequence to something like below:

```
def search_for params
  return Cache.for( params ) { HTTParty.get( URL, params ) }
end
```

You can add a modified `for` method like below:

```
class Cache
    # alias the original `for` as `lookup`
    singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :lookup, :for)

    def self.for params, &block
        value = lookup(params);
        if (block_given? and not value) then
            value = block.call
            set params, value
        end
        value
    end
end
```